# what to use instead of deprecated "LegacyContext" type in phonegap android application?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

I'm developing a PhoneGap application in Android , some plug-ins contain this line of code:

```
LegacyContext c = this.ctx;
```

this item (`"LegacyContext c"`) is very useful, and even in the realization of my plugins I make extensive use of it for working with views, activity, and more. However, the eclipse intellisense reports it as "deprecated". So it is wrong to use LegacyContext type objects? what type of object should I use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check [new plugin dev guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins) this wil help you, so Now you can use **cordova.getContext()**

The legacy ctx member is deprecated, and will be removed six months after 2.0 is released. All the methods that ctx has exist on the Context, so both getContext() and getActivity() are capable of returning the proper object required.

Comment: Note that in the meantime cordova.getContext() seems to be deprecated.

Comment: so in cordova 3.1 you would use cordova.getActivity()

Comment: This solved my problem cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext() instead of using cordova.getContext()   and cordova version is 2.4